# Azure Resource Lock - Bypassed by Powershell Remove-AzureVM

Tags: azure, powershell, resources, azure-resource-lock

In my Azure Subscription...

Created a new Resource Group LOCK using Powershell for a CLASSIC Resource Group.
New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName MYRG_DeleteLock -ResourceGroupName MYRG

I have a CLASSIC Stoage Account and a CLASSIC VM within this Resource Group.
As expected, when I tried deleting the VM from the Azure Portal it PROTECTED the deletion and notified that "Failed to delete the VM".

But when I used the below POWERSHELL command it just deleted it BYPASSING the lock on the RESOURCE GROUP.
Remove-AzureVM -DeleteVHD -ServiceName MYSERVICE -Name MYVM

Am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Remove-AzureVM` Cmdlet is for managing classic resources using `Azure Service Management API` that has no idea about `Azure Resource Manager (ARM)`. Management locks are part of ARM. This is why when you called `Remove-AzureVM`, it ignored the lock on the resource group (simply because it is not aware of such a thing) and deleted the VM.

Comment: Is there a way to create **classic aware** Resource Group locks?